# Is it a good idea to use has_one nested attributes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, has-one

Let's say if I have 3 models; **Hotel, Resort and restaurant.**
Each model have similar attributes; **title, description, facilities ...and so on...**

If I want every models have one location with attributes; **Country, Province, City, address, Latitude and Longitude.**

Should I create location model and using *has_one nested attributes* or *should I include location's attributes to those model*?
Which one is more preferable or better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use polymorphic association as you need on model to belong to more than one model. You can use it like this:

Edit: Changing the `belongs_to :address` to `belongs_to :locatable` as @vee corrected it.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :locatable, polymorphic: true
end

class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, as: :locatable    
end
class Resort < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, as: :locatable    
end
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, as: :locatable    
end
```

More Details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would recommend following naming convention and updating `belongs_to` to `:locatable` and `Hotel`, `Resort` and `Restaurant`s' `has_one` to `has_one :location, as: :locatable`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers, I've never come across polymorphic association before. Will give it a try

Comment: Yes that is the best solution I think to your problem. It will also not cause any redundancy which may happen in other associations.